# How do I manipulate data in a list that has been read in from a file using Python 2.x?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to create a program that will tally the cost of ingredients within a recipe and return a total cost for said recipe. I am teaching myself Python and have set this as a personal, but practical, challenge. However, I have hit a wall. Hard.

My idea was to read a file into a list. Multiply the ingredient within the list by the comma separated numeral. Add it all together, and return a single float for the overall cost.

```
#Phase 1 - MASTER INGREDIENTS LIST
flour_5lb = 2.5
sugar_4lb = 2.0
butter_lb = 3.0
eggs_doz = 3.0


#PHASE 2 - COST PER UNIT CONVERSION
flour_cup = flour_5lb*(1.0/20)
sugar_cup = sugar_4lb*(1.0/8)
butter_Tbsp = butter_lb*(1.0/32)
eggs_each = eggs_doz*(1.0/12)

#PHASE THREE - RECIPE ASSESSMENT
def main():
    fileObject = open("filname.txt", "r")
    fileLines = fileObject.readlines()
    fileObject.close()

    for line in fileLines:
        print line
    print "\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The `for line in fileLines:` statement prints the following:

```
flour_cup, .5

milk_cup, .4

eggs_each, 3

butter_Tbsp, 3

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Use `line.split(',')` to get a list for each line, then you can separate the fields.  Don't forget these are strings, so you will need `float()` to convert the amount.  You get double spacing because `readlines()` preserves the line-ending in the file, then `print` adds another.  You can get rid of the line ending with `line = line.rstrip()`

Comment: As beginner line up the "=" signs so they are easier to debug. There no milk_cup, in phase 1 or 2   and this works:   print line, "\n"

Comment: STOP! You should look up how to use dictionaries in python.. then the above task would be simpler.  Right now, you have to do many for loops on lists.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have to  parse your file.
For this you need to know the format in which the ingredients are being stored. Since this program is for your personal use you may just choose the most simple.

So let's assume you have your ingredients in CSV format:

```
sugar 10g
flour 20g
...
```

Then you can use pythons buildin function `split` and iteration to obtain a list of list `[['sugar', '10g'], ['flour', '10g'], ...]`.

Getting the amounts into python floats is a little tricky, since we haave to concern ourselves with the units.

Again - choose a fixed set of units to make your life a little easier.
Then use the `in` statement or the builtin function which checks if a given string has a certain suffix. (I will leave it to you to find this function.)

Then the hard part is done. Hope I could help without giving too much away.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your difficulty is knowing how to split your input on the comma -- use `split()`.  Another problem is converting the string to a float -- use `float()`.

Your last problem is mapping input strings to values.  You could write a function that maps strings to costs:

```
if item == "milk_cup":
    return milk_cup
if item == "flour_cup":
    return flour_cup
...
```

...but the better way ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) to do it is to use a dictionary.

In my sample below I've used `dict()` to make the dictionary as then I don't have to quote every string.

Here's a sample:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                               

pricelist = dict(                                                               
    flour_cup=1.0,                                                              
    milk_cup=0.4,                                                               
)                                                                                                                                        

input = ["flour_cup, 0.5", "milk_cup, 0.4"]                                       

total = 0                                                                       

for line in input:                                                              
    item, qty = line.split(",")                                                 
    item = item.strip()                                                         
    qty = float(qty)                                                            
    if item in pricelist:                                                       
        cost = qty * pricelist[item]                                            
        print "%s: %.02f\n" % (item, cost)                                      
        total += cost                                                           
    else:                                                                       
        print "I don't know what '%s' is" % item                                

print "Total: %.02f" % total
```